# CSR file generated from my NEW MAC is not accepted to create a new certificate.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, keychain, csr

I have a new MAC now , I tried to upload a CSR file generated from my new MAC to create a certificate , when i Upload the file and click on Generate nothing happens.
I went back to the old MAC "which I used before to upload CSR file" and generate a new CSR file , upload it and it was accepted with no problem .

HOW can I do it from my NEW MAC?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to revoke your old certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your new mac keychain is not having the public and private keys of old mac

Comment: what if I totally lost my old mac , I want to start over from the beginning .